# Get the String value of the EditText which has inputType numberPassword

Tags: android, android-edittext, passwords, android-inputtype

I would like to get the `String` value of an `EditText` that has the attribute `inputType`: `numberPassword`, how do I do it?

`Code_pin.getText().ToString()` always returns a `null` value.

Comment: Show your code first...

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = null;

str = your_edit.getText().toString().trim(); //put your editText value in string

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) //check for empty
{
    // Do your task here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get an `Id` of the `EditText`:

```
EditText et_pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pwd);
```

your `xml` file:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_pwd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberPassword" />
```

then you call `getText()` method:

```
String text = et_pwd.getText().toString().trim();
if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
     // empty/blank string
}else {
     // not blank string
}
```